# Ensure string contains only numbers, periods, and possibly a leading dash

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, django

I'm still learning on regex, I need to remove all characters in the string except for the numbers(0-9), dot (.) first encounter only, and negative (-) if occurs on first index of string.

so basically if i had a string "-12,3asd45,we-678.90.45" it should give me "-12345678.9045"

This is my current code, but the problem is I just want to exclude (-) if it occurs on the first index of the string, currently it excludes in all occurrences of (-):

```
value = val.replace(/[^-0-9.]/g , '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate the character set with `(?!^)-` (negative lookahead for the start of the string followed by a `-`):

```js
const val = "-12,3asd45,we-678.90"
console.log(val.replace(/[^0-9.-]|(?!^)-/g, ''));
```

To additionally remove all decimals but the first, match everything after the first `.` in a group and use a callback function to replace all periods in that group with the empty string:

```js
const val = "-12,3asd45,we-678.90.0.0.0"
const value = val
  .replace(/[^0-9.-]|(?!^)-/g, '')
  .replace(/^([^.]*\.)(.*)/, (_, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.replace(/\./g, ''));
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Note that the current logic will permit something like `1.0.1.0`, which may not be desirable

Comment: yes, tho I have already filtered not having the dots multiple times. But yes it would also be good to have the regex for dot to occur only once.

Comment: Which one do you want to keep, maybe only the first `.` encountered, remove all the rest?

Comment: yes, the first encounter will mark the rest as decimal, so its good to remove the rest of the dots.